# Django: ForeignKey(models) to not visible model?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model

below you can see a simple connection of two models via **foreignkey**!

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    user_created = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class CarModel(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    user_created = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name} ({self.manufacturer})"
```

**My Question**: is it possible to create such a connection, even if the first model (in this example the *Manufacturer*) is not created by django - so there is no typical modelclass - but still inside the same database? Like importing or loading the other model from the database to connect it? Also I'm using Postgresql!

[image]

Thanks for your help and have a great sunday!

Comment: Please Confirm Something as much as i understand you want to create the car model object without filling the manufacture field is it what you want

Comment: Not quite...I still want to fill out the manufacturer field, but this model get's created from a different application, so there won't be any model inside my django-application to refer to...

Answer (score 0):

NO, you need to create a model for Manufacturer then only you will be able to see it in any of the databases you are working in. Whether you use Postgresql or MySQL or Sqllite(in-built).
According to the MVT model, the model will be created when it is there in models.py and is registered within.

Comment: I already thought so...but thanks for the confirm!